# How to derive the time frequency and the spatial frequency when two waves undergo the beat phenomenon?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, frequency, interference, superposition

What approach would give the time frequency and spatial frequency of the beat?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.